# Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible:module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @149ed4db

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I'm getting below exception, on running the old Flutter application:

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processAlliedProdDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @149ed4db

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Java, SDK, and Flutter versions:

Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1848], locale en-PK)
• Flutter version 2.8.1 at C:\src\flutter
• Upstream repository unknown
• Framework revision 77d935af4d (1 year, 6 months ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
• Engine revision 890a5fca2e
• Dart version 2.15.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\MuhaamadUsama\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\MuhaamadUsama\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)

[√] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\MuhaamadUsama\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.66.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
• Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.134
• Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 113.0.1774.57

• No issues found!

In `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

In `gradle.properties`:

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M

Comment: Your Gradle version is too old for Java 17, or you should downgrade to Java 11. Java 17 support was introduced in Gradle 7.3. It is also possible you're building something use using a plugin which is not compatible with Java 17.

Comment: The Java version is 11.0.2, but on running flutter doctor -v it returns
 Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694) 
Unable to understand from where it reads the 17 version. How can I change to 11?

Comment: Your Java version is clearly 17.0.6. Likely you have both installed and the JAVA_HOME environment variable points to the Java 17 installation, not the Java 11 installation.